# I want to use a loop to create variables based on all named aspects of my XML window in PowerShell

Tags: wpf, powershell, user-interface

Please note that I'm not exactly an experienced coder, I'm going to uni for IT and what I'm not learning in class I'm scraping from Google and StackOverflow

I'm creating a PowerShell script with a GUI both as a challenge/practice and as a tool to help me with my part time IT imaging job. I've finished the XML portion of everything and now I'm working on the actual logic to give the window functionality.

Part of this is assigning all the named textboxes/radio buttons to variables within PowerShell which isn't difficult if you're hardcoding the variable assignments like so: `$radioButton = $window.FindName("radioButton")`

However, I've got a fair amount of textboxes/radio buttons I'd like to manipulate and while I can sit down and hard code all of them (and I probably should since these aren't subject to change), I would like to make a loop that goes through everything named within the window and creates a variable based on it, mostly for the challenge, to learn, and because it looks cleaner.

It's probably important to note that I'm not importing an .xaml file, it exists within the PS script so it doesn't need to come with an .xaml file to point to.

The whole script itself, right now unfinished because the loop I tried to make isn't working which means variables are not getting assigned:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImagingInfoSample"
        Title="Imaging Ticket Creator" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Ticket Information">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="101*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="23*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="320*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Margin="11" Width="300" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Imaging or Reimaging?"></Label>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="imgBtn" GroupName="jobType">Imaging</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name ="reimgBtn" GroupName="jobType">Reimaging</RadioButton>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Make:" ></Label>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Model:"></Label>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Tag Type/Number:"></Label>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="blkTag" GroupName="tagType">Black Tag</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="whtTag" GroupName="tagType">White Tag</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="bthTag" GroupName="tagType">Both (Fill in both boxes above if selecting this)</RadioButton>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Serial Number:"></Label>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Laptop or Desktop?"></Label>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="lapTop" GroupName="lapOrDesk">Laptop</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="deskTop" GroupName="lapOrDesk">Desktop</RadioButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="compMake" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="compModel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="blackTagBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,176,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="whiteTagBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,199,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="snBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,244,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Created Ticket">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="399*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="ticketHeader" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsReadOnly="true"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="ticketBody" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,80,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="316" IsReadOnly="true"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Short Description" Margin="0,10,309,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Ticket Body" Margin="0,54,309,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnGenTicket" Grid.Column="2" Content="Generate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object{
    try{
        Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch{
        throw
    }
}

$var_ticketHeader.Text="test"

$var_btnGenTicket.Add_Click({
    if(!$var_imgBtn.Checked -and !$var_reimgBtn.Checked){
        $var_ticketHeader.Text="Please review the ticket information!"
        $var_ticketBody.Text="Please review the ticket information!"
    }
    elseif(!$var_blkTag.Checked -and !$var_whtTag.Checked -and !$var_bthTag.Checked){
        $var_ticketHeader.Text="Please review the ticket information!"
        $var_ticketBody.Text="Please review the ticket information!"
    }
    elseif(!$var_lapTop.Checked -and !$var_deskTop.Checked){
        $var_ticketHeader.Text="Please review the ticket information!"
        $var_ticketBody.Text="Please review the ticket information!"
    }
    else{
        $var_ticketHeader.Text="Hooray! Radio buttons are working!"
        $var_ticketBody.Text="Hooray! Radio buttons are working!"
    }

})


$Null = $window.ShowDialog()
```

The piece of code I'm trying to get work but isn't:

```
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object{
    try{
        Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch{
        throw
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working or what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` in my profile and make frequent use of `Write-Verbose` to ensure I'm in a loop or to verify variable assignemtn/value. Given the answers below, you either had no objects and never entered your loop, or a value is null/unassigned. In your case, I would have `Write=Verbose $_.Name` as the first line inside the `ForEach` while I was playing with it.

Comment: @KeithMiller Thank you for the helpful tip! I'm gonna keep that in mind for the future because I'm sure something like that will be immensely helpful for debugging later down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]")`

doesn't work, because the `Name` attributes in the input XAML document are *namespace-qualified* (`x:Name`)

In order to query these attributes via an XPath query passed to [`.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectNodes), you need to:

- pass a *namespace manager* object as the second argument, in which the same namespace *URI* as in the input document is mapped to a *prefix* (which may also be `x`, but doesn't have to be).
- qualify your attribute reference with that prefix in the XPath query.

To spell it out:

```bash
# Create a namespace manager for the input document.
$nsMgr = [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]::new($xaml.NameTable)

# Add the relevant URI for the Name attributes, using a self-chosen
# prefix that may be but needn't be the same as in the input document.
$nsMgr.AddNamespace('x', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml')

# Use the self-chosen prefix in the XPath query.
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@x:Name]", $nsMgr) |
  ForEach-Object{
    # Create a var_* variable for every control in the window, named for that control.
    Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $window.FindName($_.Name)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains it simply enough that what I don't completely understand, such as the use of the namespace manager since I haven't seen that before, I can easily look up and explore further into. I appreciate this immensely!

Answer (score 0):

Try following Xml Linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$xaml = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImagingInfoSample"
        Title="Imaging Ticket Creator" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Ticket Information">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="101*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="23*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="320*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Margin="11" Width="300" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Imaging or Reimaging?"></Label>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="imgBtn" GroupName="jobType">Imaging</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name ="reimgBtn" GroupName="jobType">Reimaging</RadioButton>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Make:" ></Label>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Model:"></Label>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Tag Type/Number:"></Label>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="blkTag" GroupName="tagType">Black Tag</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="whtTag" GroupName="tagType">White Tag</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="bthTag" GroupName="tagType">Both (Fill in both boxes above if selecting this)</RadioButton>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Serial Number:"></Label>
                        <Label FontWeight="Bold" Content="Laptop or Desktop?"></Label>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="lapTop" GroupName="lapOrDesk">Laptop</RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="deskTop" GroupName="lapOrDesk">Desktop</RadioButton>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="compMake" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,92,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="compModel" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="blackTagBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,176,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="whiteTagBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,199,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="snBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,244,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Created Ticket">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="399*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="ticketHeader" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,35,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsReadOnly="true"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="ticketBody" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,80,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="424" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="316" IsReadOnly="true"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Short Description" Margin="0,10,309,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="Ticket Body" Margin="0,54,309,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnGenTicket" Grid.Column="2" Content="Generate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xaml)
$xNs = $doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('x')
$descendants = $doc.Descendants()
$named = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($descendants, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) $x.Attribute($xns + "Name") -ne $null})

$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($name in $named)
{
   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
      'Tag Name'=$name.Name.LocalName
      Name=$name.Attribute($xns + "Name").Value
      Value=$name.value
   }
   $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
}
$table | Format-Table
```

Results

```
Tag Name    Name         Value
--------    ----         -----
RadioButton imgBtn       Imaging
RadioButton reimgBtn     Reimaging
RadioButton blkTag       Black Tag
RadioButton whtTag       White Tag
RadioButton bthTag       Both (Fill in both boxes above if selecting this)
RadioButton lapTop       Laptop
RadioButton deskTop      Desktop
TextBox     compMake
TextBox     compModel
TextBox     blackTagBox
TextBox     whiteTagBox
TextBox     snBox
TextBox     ticketHeader
TextBox     ticketBody
Button      btnGenTicket
```